# Fun + Frustration with TypeScript Mapped Types

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

## Introduction to problem

I am struggling to develop strong typing for a particular function written in TypeScript...

For illustrative purposes, lets say I work at the Department of Motor Vehicles and have a function `registerVehicles` that can accept registration details for many vehicles organised by name, and returns the license plates for each vehicle.

```
interface RegistrationDetails {
    transmission?: 'manual' | 'automatic';
    wheelCount?: number;
    horsePower?: number;
}

const licensePlates = registerVehicles({
    sportsCar: {
        transmission: 'manual',
        wheelCount: 4,
        horsePower: 762
    },
    motorBike: {
        transmission: 'manual',
        wheelCount: 2
    },
    hoverBoard: {
        // All registration details are optional
    }
});
```

The function returns an object with the names of each vehicle and their newly registered license plates:

```
expect(licensePlates).to.eql({
    sportsCar: 'ABCD-1234',
    motorBike: 'SPDY-5678',
    hoverBoard: 'BTTF-2'
});
```

The function exists and works perfectly, **the problem is getting it strongly typed**.

## The solution must meet the following criteria:

1. The variable `licensePlates` should be implicitly typed from the result of the function.
2. Trying to pass a registration detail that doesn't exist should error at compile time.

   ```
   registerVehicles({
       car: {
           cowPower: 500 // <-- Spelling mistake, should be horsePower
       }
   })
   ```
3. Trying to access the license plate of a vehicle you didn't register should error at compile time:

   ```
   const licensePlates = registerVehicles({
       ferrari: {
           horsePower: 562
       }
   });

   alert(licensePlates.furrari); // <-- Spelling mistake, should be ferrari
   ```
4. TypeScript should know each license plate is a string at compile-time

   ```
   const licensePlates = registerVehicles({
       ferrari: {}
   });

   alert(licensePlates.ferrari * 5); // <-- Error, you can't multiple a string
   ```

I've gotten close, but every solution I try ultimately fails to meet at least one of the above requirements. Help me Stack Overflow community, you're my only hope!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The utility types "Record" does what you want. With it you can map dynamic properties from one type to another type. ([Try it in the Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20RegistrationDetails%20%7B%0D%0A%20transmission%3F%3A%20'manual'%20%7C%20'automatic'%3B%0D%0A%20wheelCount%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20horsePower%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20registerVehicles%3CK%20extends%20string%3E(p%3A%20Record%3CK%2C%20RegistrationDetails%3E%20)%3A%20Record%3CK%2C%20string%3E%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20return%20null%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20licensePlates%20%3D%20registerVehicles(%7B%0D%0A%20sportsCar%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20transmission%3A%20'manual'%2C%0D%0A%20wheelCount%3A%204%2C%0D%0A%20horsePower%3A%20762%0D%0A%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20motorBike%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20transmission%3A%20'manual'%2C%0D%0A%20wheelCount%3A%202%0D%0A%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20hoverBoard%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%2F%2F%20All%20registration%20details%20are%20optional%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AregisterVehicles(%7B%0D%0A%20car%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20cowPower%3A%20500%20%2F%2F%20%3C--%20Spelling%20mistake%2C%20should%20be%20horsePower%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20licensePlates2%20%3D%20registerVehicles(%7B%0D%0A%20ferrari%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20horsePower%3A%20562%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aalert(licensePlates2.furrari)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%3C--%20Spelling%20mistake%2C%20should%20be%20ferrari%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20licensePlates3%20%3D%20registerVehicles(%7B%0D%0A%20ferrari%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aalert(licensePlates3.ferrari%20*%205)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%3C--%20Error%2C%20you%20can't%20multiple%20a%20string)):

```
function registerVehicles<K extends string>(p: Record<K, RegistrationDetails> ):  Record<K, string> { 
    return null;
}
```

The `K` type will be a String Literal Types eg. `"sportsCar" | "motorBike" | "hoverBoard"`.

Update: It is not well documented. But here is [a link to the Documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) and I found [a example](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#partial-readonly-record-and-pick) here.

Comment: @Magu, I'm curious if you have some creative ideas on https://stackoverflow.com/q/46596846/678505, which I think take TS mapped types even to the next level :-)